# declare java class as private trigger compilation error

Tags: java

According to java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html

> You can also add modifiers like public or private at the very
>   beginning—so you can see that the opening line of a class declaration
>   can become quite complicated. The modifiers public and private, which
>   determine what other classes can access MyClass, are discussed later
>   in this lesson. The lesson on interfaces and inheritance will explain
>   how and why you would use the extends and implements keywords in a
>   class declaration. For the moment you do not need to worry about these
>   extra complications.
>
> In general, class declarations can include these components, in order:
>
> 1. Modifiers such as public, private, and a number of others that you will encounter later.
> 2. The class name, with the initial letter capitalized by convention.
> 3. The name of the class's parent (superclass), if any, preceded by the keyword extends. A class can only extend (subclass) one parent.
> 4. A comma-separated list of interfaces implemented by the class, if any, preceded by the keyword implements. A class can implement more
>      than one interface.
> 5. The class body, surrounded by braces, {}.

But the compiler complain with a message Modifier 'private' not allowed here when declare a class (top level class) with private modifier.

this is my code

```
private class MyPrivateClass {

}
```

and the error message in compilation

```
1: error: modifier private not allowed here
```

Comment: Is this a top-level class or an inner class?

Comment: a top-level class as per tutorial link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [section 8.1.1 of the Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1):

> The access modifiers `protected` and `private` pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration.

In other words, a private class is only allowed if it is enclosed within another class.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, the java tutorial do not mention that private only allowed for class inside a class.